# Unable to click on proceed to payment button using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.className("pull-right"));
WebElement payment_button =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Proceed To Payment')]"));
          payment_button.click();
```

Here's a [link to the page](https://www.vipcars.com/search-new/?aff=vipcar&language=en&pickup_country=441&pickup_city=9747&pickup_location=14927&dropoff_country=441&dropoff_city=9747&dropoff_location=14927&pickup_date=2016-10-28&pickup_time=10:00&dropoff_date=2016-10-29&dropoff_time=10:00&rc=in_1&driver_age=29&currency=INR&show_multilingual=1&custom_css=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vY29tbW9uL2Nzcy9uZXdmb3JtLmNzcw==&step2url=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vc2VhcmNoLW5ldy8=&terms_page=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vdGVybXNfY29uZGl0aW9ucw==&googlemap=1&page=book&car_id=10067709).

Error message at console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

Comment: try once with this xpath "//button[@class='subMitBtnInc ProcPay'][@id='proceeed_to_payment']"

Comment: No,it is still not working. Same error message at console.

Comment: @PotnuruRavi Any more suggestions my friend? it is not working.

Comment: @jackyghai The payment button and most of the elements in the page are inside an iframe with id 'supplycarsIframe'. Are you changing context to the iframe before you try to locate the button? If you are not using an explicit wait to search for this button, use the ExpectedConditions visibility check...

Comment: @Grasshopper I have done & checked every possibility as mentioned by you but still got an error message 'element not found'... specific personal information div is not in iframe but if still I try to switch into iframe before locating the button it shows an error message - no such element found.

Comment: @Grasshopper Can you comment me the exact code I should work on?

Comment: @Grasshopper able to see another element on same div but not the BUTTON                                                                                          
       driver.findElement(By.className("secure-seal"));
       WebElement secure =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Secure Transaction')]"));
          System.out.println("Seal: " + secure.getText());
          
          
         
          WebElement payment_button =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Proceed To Payment')]"));
          payment_button.click();

Comment: @jackyghai Can you add your relevant code to the question...

Comment: @jackyghai I have added the code in answer below... Tried on Chrome...

Comment: @Grasshopper Pls check out  driver.findElement(By.className("secure-seal"));
       WebElement secure =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Secure Transaction')]"));
          System.out.println("Seal: " + secure.getText());

Comment: @Grasshopper  driver.findElement(By.className("pull-right"));
          WebElement payment_button =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Proceed To Payment')]"));
          payment_button.click();

Comment: @Grasshopper Link: https://www.vipcars.com/search-new/?aff=vipcar&language=en&pickup_country=441&pickup_city=9747&pickup_location=14927&dropoff_country=441&dropoff_city=9747&dropoff_location=14927&pickup_date=2016-10-28&pickup_time=10:00&dropoff_date=2016-10-29&dropoff_time=10:00&rc=in_1&driver_age=29&currency=INR&show_multilingual=1&custom_css=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vY29tbW9uL2Nzcy9uZXdmb3JtLmNzcw==&step2url=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vc2VhcmNoLW5ldy8=&terms_page=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vdGVybXNfY29uZGl0aW9ucw==&googlemap=1&page=book&car_id=10067709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for iframe to be visible and also button to be visible before interacting with it

```
    driver.get("https://www.vipcars.com/search-new/?aff=vipcar&language=en&pickup_country=441&pickup_city=9747&pickup_location=14927&dropoff_country=441&dropoff_city=9747&dropoff_location=14927&pickup_date=2016-10-28&pickup_time=10:00&dropoff_date=2016-10-29&dropoff_time=10:00&rc=in_1&driver_age=29&currency=INR&show_multilingual=1&custom_css=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vY29tbW9uL2Nzcy9uZXdmb3JtLmNzcw==&step2url=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vc2VhcmNoLW5ldy8=&terms_page=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmlwY2Fycy5jb20vdGVybXNfY29uZGl0aW9ucw==&googlemap=1&page=book&car_id=10067709");

new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("supplycarsIframe")));
                                driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("supplycarsIframe")));

new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("proceeed_to_payment")));

WebElement procPay = driver.findElement(By.id("proceeed_to_payment"));

System.out.println(procPay.getText());

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Getting this message now.  Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: supplycarsIframe

Comment: @Grasshoppper  
 
Getting this message now.  Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: supplycarsIframe

Comment: increased timeout time 30 seconds , still doesn't solve the purpose & I am working on quite good network connection.

Comment: increased timeout time 30 seconds , still doesn't solve the purpose & I am working on quite good network connection

Comment: increased timeout time 30 seconds , still doesn't solve the purpose & I am working on quite good network connection

Comment: remove the first wait and check if it works or just use a plain Thread.sleep for 5 secs. BTW does the page load completely?

Comment: it works after removing first wait :) .. thanks mate ..thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

try once with below code

```
d1.switchTo().frame("supplycarsIframe");
d1.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='subMitBtnInc ProcPay'][@id='proceeed_to_payment']")).click();
d1.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to scroll down after waiting for everything to be loaded so the button is actually visible, only then can you click it